# Stopping or Playing AVAudioPlayer From Another Class - App Crashes - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I have an AVAudioPlayer set up in my AppDelegate to play on startup. It continues playing throughout the app, but when I try to stop or play the player in a different class, the app crashes with EXC_BAD_ACCESS on that line.

AppDelegate.swift

```
import AVFoundation

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
var window: UIWindow?
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("backgroundMusic", ofType: "wav")
var soundTrack = AVAudioPlayer()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: NSDictionary?) -> Bool {
    soundTrack = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: path), error: nil)
    soundTrack.numberOfLoops = -1
    soundTrack.volume = 0.35
    soundTrack.play()

    return true
}
```

OtherClass.swift

```
func aFunction() {
    let appDelegate = AppDelegate()
    appDelegate.soundTrack.stop()     //Here is where the app crashes. Same with .play()
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

by doing `AppDelegate()` you are creating a new instance of app delegate; one which the variables haven't been initiated. You want to get the UiApplications shared delegate:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as AppDelegate
```

Comment: Thank you, Jonah. I appreciate your answer.